# Designing for different NORMAL phone screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

**Designing for multiple phone screen sizes**

There are out there *thousands* of android devices with different screen sizes, resolutions and densities. So what should you do when designing layouts that should supports almost **every** size of **Normal** android device? (Samsung Galaxy J5, Nexus 5, etc (*Not tablets*))

- How to support different size of phone screens? (Samsung Galaxy S6's screen size is 5.1" screen size, 1440x2560p screen resolution)  and **all the other phone screen sizes**.

**Because** when you make an layout with 2 *ImageViews* and a single *TextView*, and then review it on example. Samsung Galaxy J5, it looks fine. Then you review/download it on **another phone** that is example. Samsung Galaxy S5, some of the things are in the wrong places and you definitely think that the TextView should be 56dps on the left...

- ***How to do another layout for another screen size?***

*Note: I only asked about *How to support multiple* ***Normal Phone*** *sizes?* Not about "How to support all the devices (**TABLETS, PHONES, WEARS**)?"

Comment: Have you seen the official Android documentation/tutorials on this topic? [Designing for Multiple Screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) and [Supporting Multiple Screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) amongst others.

Comment: you should not be using hard height/width dimensions and instead use either wrap_content or match_parent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Layouts for Multiple Screen Sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726764/android-layouts-for-multiple-screen-sizes)